# asp.net - How to add controls dynamically when click button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to add controls but it is overwriting.

In the below image If I click Add more Visa button I want to display all these fields.

Code:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<div id="divreg" runat="server">
<table id="tbl" runat="server">
<tr>
     <td class="style8"> Visa Number:</td>
     <td class="style20"><asp:TextBox ID="txtUser" Width="160px" runat="server"/></td>
     <td class="style22"> Country Name:</td>
     <td class="style23">
     <asp:DropDownList ID="dropCountry" Width="165px" runat="server"> </asp:DropDownList></td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td class="style22"> Type of Visa:</td>
     <td class="style23"><asp:DropDownList ID="dropVisa" Width="165px" runat="server">                    </asp:DropDownList></td>
     <td class="style22"> Type of Entry:</td>
     <td class="style23">
     <asp:DropDownList ID="dropEntry" Width="165px" runat="server">
     </asp:DropDownList> </td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
     <td class="style8"> Expiry Date</td>
     <td class="style20">
     <BDP:BasicDatePicker ID="BasicDatePicker4" runat="server" onselectionchanged="BasicDatePicker2_SelectionChanged" 
 AutoPostBack="True" />
  </td>
   <td class="style22"><asp:Button ID="btnAddVisa" Text="Add More Visa" runat="server" OnClick="btnAddVisa_Click" /> </td>

 </tr></table></div>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Code .cs:

```
static int i = 0;
    protected void btnAddVisa_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        i++;
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(divReg);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<BR>"));
        }

    }
```

Image:
Here I click Add More Visa button I want to display these all fields again

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Create a User Control to represent all that is added and then add the control as a whole. Make sure to use the LoadControl method and not the constructor of the control. You also need to keep enough information in ViewState to recreate the control on Page_Load. In your case just the number of controls should be enough.